# How to show "anything" buffers always in new window

Tags: emacs

I'm using Anything (renamed to helm recently), but I don't really like its window-splitting strategy. Looks like Anything displays its buffer in a separate window if there is currently only one opened, or reuses other window if there are more than 1 already opened.

What I would like to force is to show Anything buffer *always* in a new window which splits current one horizontally in a half.

Is that somehow possible to configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the variable `helm-display-function`. The following setting seems to work:

```
(setq helm-display-function
      (lambda (buf)
        (split-window-horizontally)
        (other-window 1)
        (switch-to-buffer buf)))
```